# Angular 4 routing/state problems

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

I have a user.service.ts file with a login method:

```
   login(userName : string, password : string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http
      .post(
      this.baseUrl + '/auth/login',
      JSON.stringify({ userName, password }),{ headers }
      )
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this._authNavStatusSource.next(true);
        return true;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

That is called by a login button on my login-form.component.ts:

```
login({ value, valid }: { value: Credentials, valid: boolean }) {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.isRequesting = true;
    this.errors='';
    if (valid) {
      this.userService.login(value.email, value.password)
      .finally( () =>
        this.isRequesting = false
      )
        .subscribe(
        result => {
          if (result) {
            console.log("calling routing navigate");
             this.router.navigate(['/connect']);
             console.log(this.userService.isLoggedIn())
             console.log("done");
          }
        },
        error => this.errors = error);
    }
  }
}
```

When someones clicks login with valid credentials, the auth_token is created on local storage, and in console I can see the result from:

```
    console.log("calling routing navigate");
     this.router.navigate(['/connect']);
     console.log(this.userService.isLoggedIn())
     console.log("done");
```

it is:

```
calling routing navigate
true
done
```

But nothing happens on the page. The login page stays and the users dont get routed to the /connect page, and the Login button on navbar continues (even that it is equal to !isLogged).

Then, I press F5 and everything goes ok. Do you have any thoughts on what is causing this behavior?

My app.module.ts:

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegistrationFormComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent },
    { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent},
    { path: 'connect', component: ConnectorComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
]
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginFormComponent,
        LogoutComponent,
        ConnectorComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    providers: [AuthGuard, ConfigService, UserService, AuthModule],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        DashboardModule,
        AuthModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ]
})
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? The key reasons that a route won't show is that an error was generated or that the routes are not configured appropriately. How is your connect route configured?

Comment: have you set the `<base href="/">` in the index.html page header

Comment: @DeborahK no errors on console. All my routes are on my main module, and works correctly when I go directly from the browser. Sometimes, when I keep pressing Log in eventually the page changes (?).

Comment: @ModarNa could you explain it a little more? I don't use it on others components, and everything works fine. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Can you show the code for your module that contains your route configuration?

Comment: @DeborahK route configuration added. Forgot to say that this angular app is being pre-rendered on server side, and I don't know if it's possible that this can affect routing.

Comment: I don't see a `connect` route defined? `this.router.navigate(['/connect']);`

Comment: Sorry, I've mistakenly removed it when posting on stackoverflow (my app has several routes so I've removed the ones that doesn't relate to the issue itself).

Comment: @DeborahK problem was not with routing. i've posted an answer. thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue was not in routing, but, in an **BehaviorSubject**.

When I was being routed to **/connect**, Angular routed me back to **/login** cause it won't detected that was logged in.

This was caused because I've provided my **UserService** two times, so, I was looking for a second instance of my **BehaviorSubject**, leading to this errors.

Thank you all for the help.